# Blank screen ... no BIOS loading screen either 

Tags: 10.04

I don't even know how long it's been but I had given up. until now.

My screen does not come on AT ALL, not even and the BIOS loading screen. I have to connect it to my TV in order to see.

But there's one thing that has always started it back up, and that is by running a hardware Diagnostics * Provided by DELL* .

It is definitely has something to do with Ubuntu. I know that for sure, because I remember running an update and BAM. That was it for the screen.

How could I restore my screen back to life ?

I have a Nvidia braphics card.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't see a BIOS loading screen i doubt it is ubuntu's fault.

I never heared anything about a Nvidia driver destroying the firmware.

Maybe your BIOS is set to some sort of "Quick Boot mode" and "Show Logo = Off" mode?
You may try to press
 `DEL` or `F2` according to your Bios.

Also check the Inputsource of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

These are some solutions I found, I haven't yet tried them, but they seem very promising ...

DELL POST /// -

Try this. Remove cover over power button, above the print screen button is a

connector, press the left side first down then the right side down. Turn on

computer and see if that fixed it. I had black screen (ERROR 2000-0333) and

did this and fixed it, takes longer to get cover on/off than the fix...lol

lookup "Problems With Portable LCD Screen"

---

PCTECHBYTES /// -

Run the BIST Test On Your Dell Laptop

To begin the BIST test, you should hold down the FN key and press the power

button. Release them both, and this should begin the BIST test. You should see

two colored bars appear on the screen, then text asking if you saw them.

Select NO to begin the test. You will see several different screens displayed

along with beeping and an error screen at the end. The error message is

normal. During the test, you should be looking for the same symptoms you’re

getting within Windows, such as lines on the LCD screen, poor color, etc.

If you do not see these problems, then the issue is likely with a bad Windows

driver. You should visit the Dell support site and get the latest driver for

your graphics card and update the system’s BIOS.

If you did see the same issues you experience within Windows, then you have a

physical problem with the LCD screen and it will likely need to be replaced.

---

WIKIPEDIA /// :

The EDID is often stored in the monitor in a memory device called a serial

PROM (programmable read-only memory) or EEPROM (electrically erasable PROM)

and is accessible via the I²C bus at address 0x50.[1] The EDID PROM can often

be read by the host PC even if the display itself is turned off.
Many software packages can read and display the EDID information, such as

read-edid[2] and PowerStrip[3] for Microsoft Windows and XFree86 (which will

output the EDID to the log if verbose logging is on (startx -- -logverbose 6))

for Linux and BSD unix. On Linux you can also see the raw EDID in hexadecimal

format if you run "xrandr --verbose". Mac OS X natively reads EDID information

(see /var/log/system.log[citation needed] or hold down Cmd-V on startup) and

programs such as SwitchResX[4] or DisplayConfigX[5] can display the

information as well as use it to define custom resolutions.

I hope this helps others.

Iv'e noticed that blank screens are becoming a larger problem in the linux/ubuntu community.

Number 1 worked for me perfectly, but only once, or at least until I run the diagnostics again.

My screen has yet be been fixed, I will update when It does and post the answer to what solved it for me.

SOURCES///////
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19235433.aspx
http://www.pctechbytes.com/dell/dell-laptop-screen-lcd-diagnostics
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data